# osx download from GRUB

Tags: grub2, macosx

Ok so I just installed Ubuntu onto my mac, but I pressed the wrong button and deleted osx.  I have the original boot disk that I used years ago on it, but after messing around on the GRUB for a bit,  I can't seem to find a way to boot from that disk.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Avi.
GRUB can be used for CD boot, but it is quite harder to do this. Instead, do the following:

1. Insert the Recovery DVD on the tray
2. Reboot the computer
3. Shortly after the computer specs show up during boot, and before GRUB loads up, press "C"
4. Your computer should automatically boot from the CD.

Altough, some computers have problems with OpenFirmware, so press the CMD key on your keyboard during boot, and so the avaiable devices are listed.

Not yet? Then hold "Option" + "Command" + "O" + "F". This should open OpenFirmware's menu. At the command prompt, type: `boot cd:,\\:tbxi`

This should do it.

Source: http://mac.linux.be/content/booting-open-firmware

Comment: None of the above seemed to work, I just kept being directed back to the GRUB.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Then, you should create a menu entry in GRUB. Here is a tutorial for this: http://superuser.com/a/58513